# Fallback to default language when node not translated to current language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I set up a multilingual blog site with Drupal 8 (in English and Japanese). What I want to do is create a blog in two languages. The default language is English. Mostly, the author will be translating the articles to Japanese and sometimes no translation.

So for the nodes I have to display the original content if there is no translation available with japanese url.

For ex: http://example.comarticle/article-title is the english node and  I have no translation for this node. So http://example.com/ja/article/article-title should show the English node content where ja is the japanese language code.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Isn't this is Drupal's default behavior? Where exactly do you need help?

Comment: No drupal is giving a 404 page for untranslated nodes.

Comment: As a workaround: The the canonical urls (e.g. `/node/123` and `/ja/node/123`) are always available in all languages.

Comment: This is indeed Drupal's default behaviour - but only for canonical URLs. Your problem is that you don't have an alias for /ja/article/article-title, so it's rightly a 404.